# How to read a list of a data in firebase?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
     private void updateUI(boolean state,String uid){
    if(state) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "SUCCESSFULL", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        if(uid != null) {
            Log.d(tag,"uid is"+uid);
            database= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            action_taken_booking = database.getReference().child("Bae").child("Booking list").child(uid).child("Action taken");
            action_taken_blocked = database.getReference().child("Bae/Blocked list/" + uid + "/Action taken");
            times_blocked = database.getReference().child("Bae/Blocked list/" + uid + "/Times blocked");
            Log.d(tag,action_taken_booking.getParent().toString());
            action_taken_booking.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    booking_action_taken =  dataSnapshot.getValue(boolean.class);
                    Log.d(tag,"booking_action_taken"+booking_action_taken);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            action_taken_blocked.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    blcoked_action = (Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    Log.d(tag,"Blocked action"+blcoked_action);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            times_blocked.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    blocked_times = (Long) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                    Log.d(tag,"TimesBlocked"+blocked_times);
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
            Log.d(tag,"Upddate UI"+blcoked_action+"  "+ blocked_times);
            blocked_action_taken = (blocked_times - blcoked_action) == 0;
            if (booking_action_taken) {
                Intent nextActivity = new Intent(SigninActivity.this, HotelActivity.class);
                nextActivity.putExtra("uid", uid);
                startActivity(nextActivity);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

My code is not reading any content from the database. In fact the code is not getting into the onDataChange method.This code is written in the sign in activity. I've used auto sign in using shared preferences. Since there are several ways to sign I used update ui method to get into desired activity.

Comment: can you show us the database rules? in the firebase console, open the "rules" tab

Comment: Its in public mode

Comment: did you mean that the `read` is set to `true` on the rules' root? put this line `Log.e("databaseError", databaseError.getMessage());` inside `onCancelled()` method and let me know the message written in the logcat.